# Why is the result of my program always underweight in BMI?

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code:

```
Dim Weight, Height, Bmi_value As Integer
    Weight = TextBox1.Text
    Height = TextBox2.Text

    Bmi_value = (Weight / Height ^ 2)
    TextBox3.Text = Bmi_value

    Select Case Bmi_value
        Case 0.0 To 18.5
            TextBox4.Text = "Underweight"
        Case 18.6 To 24.9
            TextBox4.Text = "Normal"
        Case 25.0 To 29.9
            TextBox4.Text = "Overweight"
        Case Is >= 30.0
            TextBox4.Text = "Obese"

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Because your `Textbox3` is resulting to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code fixed:

```
'You were using Integer instead of Double
Dim Weight, Height, Bmi_value As Double
If you want to take the value from the textBoxes, you have to covert it to Double.
Weight = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text)
Height = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text)

'Better to call the right function Math.Pow()
Bmi_value = (Weight / Math.Pow(Height, 2))

'You have to convert it to String
TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Bmi_value)
Select Case Bmi_value
    Case 0.0 To 18.5
        TextBox4.Text = "Underweight"
    Case 18.6 To 24.9
        TextBox4.Text = "Normal"
    Case 25.0 To 29.9
        TextBox4.Text = "Overweight"
    Case Is >= 30.0
        TextBox4.Text = "Obese"
End Select
End Sub
```

There was alot of error in this code:

**First**: don't declare var as integer if you need decimal value, like with the BMI calculation.

**Second**: always convert your value to the right type if you are getting them from TextBox or if you want to print them inside a TextBox

Comment: @Simo : For the record, `^` in VB.NET is translated to `Math.Pow()` when compiled. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks for the advice, But i always prefert to call the function, also for a clear readability of the code

Comment: I used this code and the result is now 0. below always no matter how high the weight or height is

Comment: @DoinBain The code is functioning, i tried it. But i'm pretty sure that your bmi calculation is wrong because it returns something like `0.00xx` values

Comment: @DoinBain : Have you entered valid numbers inside the text boxes? Note that which decimal point to use (`,` or `.`) depends on the target computer's cultural settings. You cannot enter _anything_ other than `0` to `9`, `-` and `.` (or `,`). -- Perhaps you could give us an example of your input?

Comment: By the way, my test was my height expressed in `cm` and my weight expressed in `Kg`. But I'm 100% sure that this code works.

Comment: @Simo : The algorithm/calculation is correct. Bare in mind that `Weight` should be in kg and `Height` in **m**.

Comment: @VisualVincent yup, but this is not related with the code, just for the record

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim dblWeight As Double, dblHeight As Double, dblBMI As Double

    dblWeight = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) 'assumes lbs.
    dblHeight = CDbl(TextBox2.Text) 'assumes inches
    On Error GoTo 0
    dblBMI = ((dblWeight * 703.0#) / (dblHeight * dblHeight))
    TextBox3.Text = dblBMI
    Select Case dblBMI
        Case Is <= 18.5 : TextBox4.Text = "Underweight"
        Case 18.6 To 24.9 : TextBox4.Text = "Normal"
        Case 25.0# To 29.9 : TextBox4.Text = "Overweight"
        Case 30.0# To 34.9 : TextBox4.Text = "Obese Class I"
        Case 35.0# To 39.9 : TextBox4.Text = "Obese Class II"
        Case Is >= 40.0# : TextBox4.Text = "Obese Class III"
    End Select

    Exit Sub
```

Try this, Works for me.

Comment: The answer is always obese I or II or III help please

Comment: Your original code looks like you use the metric system (kilogram for the weight and metres for the height), but the code from this example doesn't use the metric system (don't know the name of the american system), sou you either have to type in your width and height in pound and inches or you have to change the code to calculate with kilogram and metres (change the calculation for variable dblBMI)